# Custom Order Status use and Stock Reduction / Management

Tags: woocommerce, status, inventory

I use multiple custom status updates (“WooCommerce Order Status Manager” by skyverge) to manage the flow of our orders. Each order wie create (usually manually) will run through about 5-8 different custom status updates (depending on the many stages of processes needed) before the order is changed to ‘completed’.

It takes 5-7 days for us to complete an order and stock items will be added (and sometimes removed) via the admin order pages at different stages and some times when on different (custom) statuses.

The issue we have is stock management. The inventory wont update until the order is marked as completed but due to time to complete an order – it means our stock numbers are never accurate on a day by day basis.

Is there a way to create a hook or code that will change the stock amounts (plus or minus) when ever a product is added/removed to an order? (regardless of the the order status)

Thank you kindly! any assistance / feedback would be appreciated

-IB

I tried adjusting the custom order statuses to behave like the woo commerce defaults "pending", "on hold" " paid" etc but it doesn't behave as hoped.